# Is it possible for columns to wrap and be all the same height using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

Using Bootstrap 3, is it possible to have columns wrap and be the same height as the largest column in the row?

I know it's possible to force columns to be all of the same height in the same row [using flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892773/968301), but is it possible to have the same column heights when the columns wrap?

```css
.row.display-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div[class*='col-'] {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row display-flex">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        ShouldBeSameHeightAsMultiLineColumn
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        Multi line content that will wrap to the next line. Multi line content that will wrap to the next line. Multi line content that will wrap to the next line. 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        ShouldBeSameHeightAsMultiLineColumn
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        ShouldBeSameHeightAsMultiLineColumn
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I will use jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var biggestHeight = 0;
  var flexColumns = $('.display-flex > div');
  flexColumns.each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){
      biggestHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  flexColumns.height(biggestHeight);
});
```

```css
.row.display-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div[class*='col-'] {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row display-flex">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        ShouldBeSameHeightAsMultiLineColumn
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        Multi line content that will wrap to the next line. Multi line content that will wrap to the next line. Multi line content that will wrap to the next line. 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        ShouldBeSameHeightAsMultiLineColumn
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        ShouldBeSameHeightAsMultiLineColumn
    </div>
</div>
```